# Website subscribed to calendar

Tags: ios, calendar

Some how my iPhone calendar subscribed to a website and now I get reminders of really bad things in my calendar. I cannot go to the web page to unsubscribe because it’s spam and takes me to a different website every time. Is there a way to delete this from my calendars?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried following the steps described in the 'Unsubscribe from other Calendars' section at https://support.apple.com/HT211076?

Answer (score 1):

Put your device in airplane mode and disconnect from wireless. Now you can open the calendar app and settings app and clean any accounts or subscribed calendars.

Track down all the events you feel are wrong and delete them, make note of which calendar they reside.

- https://support.apple.com/HT211076

From there, you can likely turn on networking and test you removed the data that was added as a subscription.